# MySQL join two tables which have same rows and replace specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

What do I have now is a two tables in MySQL db, one thing happened during converting tables (forum convert), and now I've an issue with encoding. I want to fix that by joining one table to another, according to ids, and ignore first table text column while replacing it by text column from other table.

Both tables have `"topic_id"` and `"threadid"` which uses same numbers to identify thread name. 
They are also have `"title"` and `"topic_title"`. There is some amount of other columns, ask if you will need and I post the other ones.

So, is it possible to check while `"topic_id == threadid"`, and replace `"topic_title"` with `"title"` using MySQL query or not?

Comment: Do you want to change the data in the table permanently or do you just want a query (`select`) that returns this data.

Comment: I want to change data permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE phpbbf_topics t1 
JOIN vb_thread t2 ON t1.topic_id = t2.threadId
SET t1.topic_title = t2.title
```

Something like this should do it.

Comment: I've tried your answer, but SQL given me this error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM phpbbf_topics t1 JOIN vb_thread t2 ON t1.topic_id = t2.threadId' at line 3" I have used the following query "UPDATE t1
SET t1.topic_title = t1.title
FROM phpbbf_topics t1
JOIN vb_thread t2 ON t1.topic_id = t2.threadId"

Comment: Updated my answer, should be ok now

Comment: Yeah it worked good, but needed to change last thing "t1.title" to "t2.title" =)

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible try this query

```
Update tbl1 A SET A.topic_title = B.title
LEFT JOIN tbl2 B ON  A.topic_id = B.threadid
```